# Ajax - Issue - Sending JavaScript Var to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have not been able to find a simple example of ajax with single variable, everything on here is made way too complicated for an AJAX beginner. I've watched about 4 different YouTube videos on the topic, but can't seem to get it right.
I have the `src` of an image in a variable like so with a JavaScript..

```
<img alt="" src="blah.jpg" style="height: 276px; width: 200px" id="imgClickAndChange1" onclick="changeImage(this)" />

<script language="javascript">
function changeImage(imagePass) {

var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
var n = num.toString();
var numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
var string = "/Images/Folder/"
var final = string.concat(numImg);
imagePass.src = final;
//(this is where I want to pass the variable imagePass.src or "final" to a php script w/ Ajax)
```

Here is my php script:

```
<?php>
include_once "code.php";  //connecting to database
$s = (this is where I want the variable to be posted);
$temp = explode('/', $s);
$temp2 = explode('.', $temp[count($temp) - 1]); //this is getting the variable I want from the variable sent(which is actually a number)
$float = (int)$temp2; //changing the number (which is a string) to an int
mysql_query("UPDATE Variable SET `upVote` = `upVote`+1 WHERE id= (variable here)) "  //Making a row in my database w/ the id of the variable add 1 to the count
?>
```

How would I go about posting and sending this w/out a page refresh? AJAX is really confusing me so a working implementation to get me started on this would be great, Thanks a lot.

//Let's just assume the php page where the script is located is called 'hello.php'

Comment: http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html The basics using jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use ajax, try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeImage(imagePass) {

        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
        var n = num.toString();
        var numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
        var string = "/Images/Folder/"
        var final = string.concat(numImg);
        imagePass.src = final;
        $.ajax({
          url : 'hello.php',
          type: 'post',
          data : {'final':final},
          success: function()
              {
                    alert('Success!');
              }
      });
   }
</script>
```

PHP script (hello.php):

```
<?php>
include_once "code.php";  //connecting to database
$s = $_POST['final'];
$temp = explode('/', $s);
$temp2 = explode('.', $temp[count($temp) - 1]); //this is getting the variable I want from the variable sent(which is actually a number)
$float = (int)$temp2; //changing the number (which is a string) to an int
mysql_query("UPDATE Variable SET `upVote` = `upVote`+1 WHERE id= (variable here)) "  //Making a row in my database w/ the id of the variable add 1 to the count
?>
```

Comment: How would the php page look? - Something like `$s = _POST` ?

Comment: Worked perfect, Thanks for your help!